# How to use enable_if when return value is either class or class<class> or class<class, class>, etc.?

Tags: c++, enable-if, template-templates

The following simplified class does different things when returning a value from get() depending on whether the class was given a double or an array as a template parameter:

```
#include "array"
#include "type_traits"

template<class T> class C
{
public:
    T get(const int arg) {
        return this->impl<T>(arg);
    }

private:
    template<class Out_T> typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<Out_T, double>::value,
        Out_T
    >::type impl(const int arg) { return 1; }

    template<class Out_T> typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<Out_T, std::array<double, 3>>::value,
        Out_T
    >::type impl(const int arg) { return {1, 2, 3}; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    C<double> c1;
    C<std::array<double, 3>> c2;

    return c1.get(0) < c2.get(0)[1];
}
```

How should I write the array version of impl so that any number of items in the array would be supported? The errors from g++-4.8.2 and clang++-3.5 were not helpful. The closest I think I've gotten is:

```
    template<
        template<class...> class Out_T,
        class... Args
    > typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<Out_T<Args...>, std::array<Args...>>::value,
        Out_T<Args...>
    >::type impl(const int arg) { return {1, 2, 3}; }
```

but clang still complains:

```
testi.cpp:8:20: error: no matching member function for call to 'impl'
                return this->impl<T>(arg);
                       ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
testi.cpp:31:28: note: in instantiation of member function 'C<std::__1::array<double, 3> >::get' requested
      here
        return c1.get(0) < c2.get(0)[1];
                              ^
testi.cpp:13:7: note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if' [with Out_T =
      std::__1::array<double, 3>]
                std::is_same<Out_T, double>::value,
                ^
testi.cpp:23:14: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template
      parameter 'Out_T'
        >::type impl(const int arg) { return {1, 2, 3}; }
                ^
```

Comment: BTW, template specialization seems simpler here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the template declaration from:

```
template<
    template<class...> class Out_T,
    class... Args
>
```

to

```
template<
    class Out_T
>
```

And change the return type to:

```
typename std::enable_if<
    detail::is_standard_array<Out_T>::value,
    Out_T
>::type
```

Where `is_standard_array` is a helper template that returns a boolean determining if the type is an `std::array`:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class T>
    struct is_standard_array : std::false_type { };

    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    struct is_standard_array<std::array<T, N>> : std::true_type { };
}
```

---

The problem was that the `Args....` parameter pack wasn't provided for the function call to `impl()` so the compiler ruled it out as a candidate overload. You could have also specialized `C` for class `std::array` and modify `get()` appropriately.

Comment: I think that declaration should be `template<class Out_T>` as in the first example, OP just has to use your `is_standard_array`.

Comment: Also, You miss the return type (`Out_T`) in the `enable_if`.

Comment: Ah yes another layer of indirection for the win, I should've remembered... This is also probably more readable than trickery inside enable_if. Thanks.